# .dat files and writing a random ascii value and converting that back into its character form

Tags: python, string, file

I am trying to create a program which creates a .txt or a .dat file (depends on user choice) and then in that file writes a random value which is then converted into another value.

so if a random character is given this should be converted into its corresponding ASCII value and vie versa.

At the moment this is what I have:

```
import random # import randomdeals with random generation
import string # import string contains sequences of common ASCII characters

userInput = input("Which file would you like to open either a .txt file or a .dat file?") # let the user decide which file type they want to open

def randomCharacter(): 
    return random.choice(string.ascii_letters)
def randomASCII():
    return random.randint(97,122)

if userInput == (".txt"):
    with open("characterConversion.txt", "w") as textFile:
        textFile.write(randomCharacter())
        textFile.close()
    textFile = open("characterConversion.txt", "r+")
    character = textFile.readline(1)
    textFile.write("\n converted into its ASCII value is \n") #/n means a new line
    textFile.write(str(ord(character)))
    textFile.close()
if userInput == (".dat"):
    with open("asciiConversion.dat", "w") as datFile:
        datFile.write(str(randomASCII()))
        datFile.close()
    datFile = open("asciiConversion.dat", "r+")
    ascii = int(datFile.readline(1))
    character = chr(randomASCII())
    datFile.write(str(ascii))
    datFile.write("\n in its character form is \n")
    datFile.write(character)
    datFile.close()
```

My .txt part of the program works great thanks to users earlier who helped me fix it but I am now having trouble with my .dat file. After I enter my input as .dat and open the file it reads: 
1061
 in its character form is 
a

However the number (in this case it is 1061) should only be between 97 and 122 so I do not know where I am going wrong. I apologise if I haven't explained my problem clearly

Answer (score 1):

doing `str(randomCharacter)` you convert the function named `randomCharacter` to string, but you don't call it.

In Python you have to put parentheses even if there aren't any parameters to pass, or it has a different meaning.

And even if you called it, you would return the function reference again not the result (looks like using VB twisted your python code). So do

```
def randomCharacter():
    return random.choice(string.ascii_letters)
```

then use a `with` context block to ensure the file is closed/flushed:

```
if userInput == ".txt":
    with open("characterConversion.txt", "w") as textFile:
        textFile.write(randomCharacter())
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to close the opened file after writing on it

```
textFile.write(str(randomCharacter()))
textFile.close()
```

Comment: OMG i can't believe I forgot to do that but when i open the file after closing it the file just says: <function randomCharacter at 0x01638D68>

Comment: You are missing the function call `()`

Answer (score 0):

You are not saving the random character that you've just created in the `randomCharacter` function anywhere. Besides that, you are returning the function itself, instead of this randomly created character.

This would work:

```
userInput = input("Which file would you like to open either a .txt file or a .dat file? ")

def randomCharacter():
    random_character = random.choice(string.ascii_letters)
    return random_character

if userInput == ".txt":
    with open("characterConversion.txt", "w") as f:
        f.write(randomCharacter())
```

Also, you don't need to use `str` function here, since the returned value by randomCharacter is already a string.

Answer (score 0):

What I needed to do was delete the second datFile.write as I was writing 2 different ASCII values as the program was alternating which value to convert